# How do I get my data into the correct format for React Native's SectionList?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, javascript-objects

I have an `allPosts` array that looks like this.

```
const allPosts = [
    {
      date: '2017-06-06',
      imageUrl: 'image1_06-06',
    },
    {
      date: '2017-06-06',
      imageUrl: 'image2_06-06',
    },
    {
      date: '2017-06-07',
      imageUrl: 'image1_06-07',
    },
    {
      date: '2017-06-07',
      imageUrl: 'image2_06-07',
    }
];
```

It needs to organized like this for React Native's `SectionList`.

```
const postsByDate = [
    {
      data: [{ imageUrl: 'image1_06-06' }, { imageUrl: 'image2_06-06' }],
      key: '2017-06-06',
    },
    {
      data: [{ imageUrl: 'image1_06-07' }, { imageUrl: 'image2_06-07' }],
      key: '2017-06-07',
    },
];
```

I'm having a hard time figuring how to deep-push the `data` for each dated `key`.

If it matters `allPosts` actually has more than imageUrl but I removed the extra data for simplicity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is time for you to learn how to use `map`, `filter` and `reduce` since you will need them all the time when changing your data structure. Here is very clean solution done with `reduce`:

```
const postsByDate = allPosts.reduce((acc, post) => {
  const foundIndex = acc.findIndex(element => element.key === post.date);
  if (foundIndex === -1) {
    return [
      ...acc, 
      {
        key: post.date,
        data: [{imageUrl: post.imageUrl}],
      },
    ];
  }
  acc[foundIndex].data = [...acc[foundIndex].data, {imageUrl: post.imageUrl}];
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks @henrik R!  This was the path I was driving down without success. I'll give this a go as soon as I get back home.

Comment: Works great and taught me a lot.  Thanks!!

Comment: Good to hear. I recommend to watch this play list to learn more on functionaly javascript programming :) https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0zVEGEvSaeEd9hlmCXrk5yUyqUag-n84

Answer (score 1):

is this you wanted?

```js
const allPosts = [
    {
      date: '2017-06-06',
      imageUrl: 'image1_06-06',
    },
    {
      date: '2017-06-06',
      imageUrl: 'image2_06-06',
    },
    {
      date: '2017-06-07',
      imageUrl: 'image1_06-07',
    },
    {
      date: '2017-06-07',
      imageUrl: 'image2_06-07',
    }
];
var keys = [];
var PostsByDate = [];
for (var i in allPosts){
    var date = allPosts[i].date;
    var temp_img = [];
    for(var j in allPosts){
        if(allPosts[j].date == date){
          temp_img.push({imageUrl:allPosts[j].imageUrl});
        }
     }
     var obj = {data:temp_img,key:date};
     PostsByDate.push(obj);
} 
console.log(PostsByDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const allPosts = [
    {
        date: '2017-06-06',
        imageUrl: 'image1_06-06',
    },
    {
        date: '2017-06-06',
        imageUrl: 'image2_06-06',
    },
    {
        date: '2017-06-07',
        imageUrl: 'image1_06-07',
    },
    {
        date: '2017-06-07',
        imageUrl: 'image2_06-07',
    }
];


var o = {}
allPosts.map(item => {
    o[item.date] = o[item.date] || { key: item.date }
    if (o[item.date].data) {
        o[item.date].data.push({ imageUrl: item.imageUrl })
    } else {
        o[item.date].data = [{ imageUrl: item.imageUrl }]
    }
})

var PostByDate = Object.keys(o).map(val => {
    return o[val]
})

console.log(PostByDate)
```